# Preventing clang-format from inserting line breaks in template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates, line-breaks, clang-format

I'm having a problem where clang-format inserts line breaks in template instantiation parameters too easily.

For example, this:

```
return std::is_trivially_constructible_v<T> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;
```

becomes:

```
return std::is_trivially_constructible_v<
           T> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;
```

This really irks me for some reason. Is there a way to make this prefer to keep the template instantiation parameters on the same line, if possible?

For example, something like this would be great:

```
return std::is_trivially_constructible_v<T>
    && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;
```

Comment: which clang-format version and which configuration do you use?